# Error running install-tl "profile key for collection-basic must be 0 or 1, not: 1"

Tags: docker, perl, aws-lambda, latex

I'm getting a very weird error trying to build texlive from scratch inside a Docker using a custom profile, mind you this exact code used to work, but after some updates to the texlive installer I get these errors now.

I get the error when I run `./install-tl --profile ../texlive.profile`, giving me  `./install-tl: Quitting, profile key for collection-basic must be 0 or 1, not: 1` which doesn't make sense to me.

[This is the line in the TexLive installer where this happens](https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer/blob/master/install-tl#L2031), but honestly I couldn't make anything out of this, can't understand perl and searching this error on google gives nothing at all.

Any help is much appreciated, this has blocked our development flow.

*The context here is that I need to build and package a very lightweight distribution of texlive to be run within AWS's Lambda service*

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7

# The TeXLive installer needs md5 and wget.
RUN yum -y install perl-Digest-MD5 && \
    yum -y install wget

WORKDIR /opt

# Download TeXLive installer.
ADD http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz /opt

# Minimal TeXLive configuration profile.
COPY texlive.profile /opt

# Install base TeXLive system.
RUN tar xf install*.tar.gz
RUN cd install-tl-* && \
    ./install-tl --profile ../texlive.profile


ENV PATH=/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH


# Install latexmk.
RUN tlmgr install latexmk

# Remove LuaTeX.
RUN tlmgr remove --force luatex

# Remove large unneeded files.
RUN rm -rf /opt/texlive/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb* \
           /opt/texlive/texmf-dist/source/latex/koma-script/doc \
           /opt/texlive/texmf-dist/doc 

RUN mkdir -p /opt/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/Digest/ && \
    mkdir -p /opt/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/auto/Digest/MD5/ && \
    cp /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Digest/MD5.pm \
       /opt/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/Digest/ && \
    cp /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Digest/MD5/MD5.so \
       /opt/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/auto/Digest/MD5

FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

WORKDIR /opt

ENV PATH=/opt/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
ENV PERL5LIB=/opt/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/

COPY --from=0 /opt/ /opt/
```

And this is my texlive.profile

```
selected_scheme scheme-custom
TEXDIR /opt/texlive
TEXMFSYSCONFIG /opt/texlive/texmf-config
TEXMFSYSVAR /opt/texlive/texmf-var
TEXMFLOCAL /opt/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFHOME /tmp/texmf
TEXMFCONFIG /tmp/texmf-config
TEXMFVAR /tmp/texmf-var
binary_x86_64-linux 1
collection-basic 1
collection-latex 1
instopt_adjustpath 0
instopt_adjustrepo 1
instopt_letter 0
instopt_portable 0
instopt_write18_restricted 1
tlpdbopt_autobackup 0
tlpdbopt_backupdir tlpkg/backups
tlpdbopt_create_formats 0
tlpdbopt_desktop_integration 0
tlpdbopt_file_assocs 0
tlpdbopt_generate_updmap 0
tlpdbopt_install_docfiles 0
tlpdbopt_install_srcfiles 0
tlpdbopt_post_code 1
```

I'm running it simply calling `docker build -t local/lambdalatex .`

Comment: Does your texlive.profile have Windows style CRLF line endings?

Comment: @Shawn How do I check/fix that?

Comment: A good editor, `file`, `cat -v`, etc., and again a good editor, or `dos2unix` to fix.

Comment: Yup that was it!